# How to check if RouteData.Values is not in asp.net webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, url-routing

I have a friendly URL which can be like

example:

1. www.abc.com/news/
2. www.abc.com/news/year/

If url is with out year then i show latest 20 news item otherwise i show news from that particulate year

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["YEAR"].ToString())) {
    _Year = int.Parse(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["YEAR"].ToString());
}
```

ABOVE code generates following error

`[System.NullReferenceException] = {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}`

I am not sure how to get around this error. How can i check if route value is null or not so that i can execute code accordingly.

Global.asax code

```
   routes.MapPageRoute("news", "news/", "~/news.aspx", false,
new RouteValueDictionary {
    {
        "path", "page-not-found"
    }, {
        "pagename", "page-not-found"
    }
});

routes.MapPageRoute("news_YearWise", "news/{YEAR}", "~/news.aspx", false,
new RouteValueDictionary {
    {
        "YEAR", "0"
    }
},
new RouteValueDictionary {
    {
        "YEAR", "[0-9]{1,8}"
    },
});
```

SOLVED:

```
   if (RouteData.Values["YEAR"] != null)
    { _Year = int.Parse(RouteData.Values["YEAR"].ToString()); }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using  `.ToString()` which was creating problem.
 Rather just use below code

```
  if (RouteData.Values["YEAR"] != null)
    { _Year = int.Parse(RouteData.Values["YEAR"].ToString()); }
```